# Re-evaluate the ModelState.IsValid property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to validate a user changing their password. The PasswordChange Class which this actionresult takes has 4 properties. one of which is the databasePassword which im compared against a "CurrentPassword" property which ensures the user can only change their password if they know their current password (pretty standard proceedure on websites)

Problem I have is the database password is only set (as shown) inside the ActionResult but the ModelState seems to get called before this so it returns false on "IsValid" because it sees the database password as "NULL"  even after the database password is set

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordChange model)
    {
        var User = GetPlayer().User;
        model.databasePassword = User.Password; 

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //update the users password
            User.Updated = SystemDate.Current();
            User.Password = model.newPassword.ToLower();

            return Redirect("/Player");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

How can I go about reevaluating it or getting it to evaluate when i want it to!

Answer (score 2):

Check the error and clear it if your assignment fixed it. Simplified check:

```
model.databasePassword = User.Password;
if (ModelState["databasePassword"].Errors.Count == 1)
{
    ModelState["databasePassword"].Errors.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a PasswordChangeInput view model class and pass in what you need from the view, you can then have separate validation from your entity model.  Then you can use something like automapper to map the input view model to the entity model after your satisfied the input data is valid.

To add: you could try and clear out the ModelState errors, set the databasePassword, and re validate.  It's probably easier to figure out what is causing the default model binder to add an error for databasePassword and change it so it doesnt.

Comment: that is pretty much what PasswordChange is. It is pretty much a view model which had 4 properties. 3 from the page one set from the database on post page.. this doesn't solve the issue with getting the modelstate to validate afterwards!

Comment: Ok, dumb question but why does databasePassword need to be a model property if CurrentPassword is?

Comment: It's really not a model of the view if you're adding things to it after it's passed back from the view.  That's why I ask why databasePassword is needed on PasswordChange.

Comment: ok fair point its more of a validation model. but if it fails it will be passed back down to the page. so in the sense it is a modelview... problem comes i guess when to validate the modelview i need to add more objects to it to validate against. I guess inside the validation instead of expecting a databasepassword I could go ahead and pull it out of the database myself.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding something, just remove databasePassword from the PasswordChange model and before the if (ModelState.IsValid)
you can test if CurrentPassword ==  User.Password, if not you can ModelState.AddModelError();

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post, but I found another solution which might help someone struggling with the same scenario.

[Conditional Validation with Data Annotations in ASP.NET MVC](http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/)

or by creating ModelState extension

[ASP.NET MVC - Excluding Model Validation Rules](http://www.compiledthoughts.com/2011/02/aspnet-mvc-excluding-model-validation.html)